# How to turn OFF escape in CSV format?

Tags: greenplum

I hope to turn off escaping for my external table which using csv files:

```
FORMAT 'csv' (delimiter ',' null '' escape 'OFF' quote '"')
```

But if I do so, I will get:

```
ERROR:  escape in CSV format must be a single character
********** Error **********

ERROR: escape in CSV format must be a single character
SQL state: 0A000
```

So how should I turn it off?

P.S. I know it will be fine to change to text format, but all my data files are in csv format and I don't want to transform then into txt.

Answer (score 1):

http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/570/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html

You currently can't disable the escape character with CSV format.  The default is a double quote too as explained in the above link.

Here is more information on how it works too:
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/570/admin_guide/load/topics/g-escaping-in-csv-formatted-files.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've read those links before, but I do not quite understand why they disable turn OFF escaping for CSV format?

Comment: Because it isn't needed.  Are you getting errors when you try to load a CSV file?

Comment: Yes, but I have solved it, by remove those quote marks. So I’m just curious about the reason

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to escape the double quotes so you can retain it?

Comment: Actually there were some quoted columns which contain comma inside, and they would be divided when I read then through GP external table. This would make the first and last columns contain a single double-quote-mark, which caused table aborting

Comment: For CSV format, a comma inside quotes will not be treated as a new delimiter.  "hi,,,,,","Taurus" would be just two CSV fields.  If your data has double quotes inside the field, you need to escape it to retain it.  You do that by just adding an additional double quote.  Without the escape functionality, the double quote in your field would end it and then the external table would fail.